# Ensuring a given set of RPMs, and only those RPMs, are installed

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, ansible

I have multiple lists of RPMs (one per configuration), and a set of remote machines. Each list includes *all* of the RPMs needed to run my machine in the configuration I choose.

For a given configuration and machine, I need to make sure that:

1. Every RPM in the configuration's RPM list is installed, in the exact same version; and
2. Any RPM *not* in the list is not installed (and uninstall it if necessary)

I've been looking into Ansible and its [yum module](http://docs.ansible.com/yum_module.html), but though it's easy ensuring given RPMs are installed, I couldn't find a way to specify that any other RPMs should be uninstalled.

What's a good way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

It's right there, in the documentation you linked:

```
- name: remove the Apache package
  yum: name=httpd state=absent
```

Note it can be applied to groups as well:

```
- name: install the 'Development tools' package group
  yum: name="@Development tools" state=absent
```

However, if your requirement is to ensure **any** package not in your list is not installed, you should start reviewing your provision procedure, i.e., if a machine is under control since its inception, there shouldn't be way out of your control for a package to be installed.

Comment: I need to ensure *any* package not on the list is not installed, and unfortunately the machine cannot be under my control since its inception.

Comment: Since this machine has not been completely under your control, I'd start by listing all the currently installed packages and working from there.

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -qa` will list all installed RPMs. You could simply save a known good servers output to a txt file and then run a diff against other servers.

I've not used Ansible, but possibly you could use this output to list packages to remove.